# So about requesting in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok look at this code..

```
var http = require('http');

var handleRequest = function (request, response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"context-type":"text/plain"});
    response.end('Welcome to the node club! :)');

}
//the createServer method... creates a server WOW!
http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8888);

console.log('The servers are running and the bacon is stopping');
```

It seems simple enough, the handleRequest function will create a writeHead function when the node will allow me to respond ...right? And if that is the case,  I will be able to write out "Welcome to the node club"  in the end method. The thing I don't understand about node is the request variable or object or whatever. **In the function am I requesting the node? Or is the node requesting me to run a function? I'm not using the request variable in the function so would it still run if I left it out?**

Comment: its the incoming request... its an object itself that you or someone else sends to the server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to [`http.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) is a function to be called on each request. The function [is documented as](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request)

> `function (request, response) { }`
>   request is an instance of [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) and response is an instance of [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

What you do in this function is up to you; it can be anything.

However, virtually all web applications end up writing an answer to the client, and that's done via the `response` object. Also, since an application that serves just one page is quite limited, most applications also want to get information from the HTTP request, including the path requested (something like `'/questions/37265770/so-about-requesting-in-node-js'`, in `request.path`), [HTTP POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295782/35070) and the like.

Your function gets called with two arguments, the first of which is the request object, the second the response object. There is no magic involved - you seem to call magic "node", but that's just the name of the project.